# Consecutive assignments in python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Is it legal to do

```
a = b = 3
```

in python? If so, is it a bad practice?

Comment: You could have tried that out in under 1 second.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but I can't try the second question out.

Comment: **IT IS NOT A GOOD PRACTICE**

Comment: @Shai: Want to elaborate on that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters need I ?

Comment: @Shai **YES IT IS GOOD PRACTICE**

Comment: Also this question isn't primarily opinion based, this is a feature of Python that should most definitely be promoted, nobody can argue against this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is legal to do so. No, it is not bad practice.

Just take into account that the right-hand side, the value expression, is evaluated first, and assignment then takes place from left to right; `3` is assigned to `a` first, then to `b`.

From the [assignment statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

You assign *the same value* to all targets. That means that each variable refers to *one* value only. This is important when that value is mutable, like a list or a dictionary.

Comment: PEP-8 advices against multiple expressions on a single line. Is this not an instance of such?

Comment: No, this is not. It is **one** *statement* (PEP 8 warns against multiple statements, not multiple expressions). PEP 8 is otherwise silent on the number of targets in an assignment.

Comment: @Vorac Where on the PEP-8? I can't seem to find it myself

Comment: @Haidro: *Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.*, referring to using `if something: true_statement` on one line, or using `;` to put multiple statements on one line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, lightning fast! I know where it is and shill you got it first. Do you search very quickly or do you just know it all by hearth :D?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, just watch out for stuff like this:

```
a = b = []
a.append(2)
print a
print b
```

Prints:

```
[2]
[2]
```

But other than that, it's fine. [@Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17314687/1714410) has a lot of information in his answer, so check it out :).

Comment: @kawing-chiu Only half an hour? Would have taken me hours to figure out